# NameAlreadyBoundException if use of @Stateless in a webservice with web.xml

Tags: web-services, weblogic, web-deployment, weblogic12c, stateless

I'm trying to deploy in Weblogic 12c a webservice using the following annotations:

```
@SchemaValidation
@BindingType(javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
@WebService(serviceName = "xxxxx",
        targetNamespace = "http://bla/BusinessServices/yyy/xxxxx/V1",
        wsdlLocation = "META-INF/wsdl/zzz/yyy/xxxxx/V1/xxxxxConcrete.wsdl",
        portName = "xxxxxPort",
        endpointInterface = "ble.businessservices.yyy.xxxxx.v1.xxxxx")
//@Transactional(value= Transactional.TransactionFlowType.SUPPORTS, version= Transactional.Version.WSAT12)
@Stateless
@SecurityPolicies(@SecurityPolicy(uri = "my_policy"))
@DeclareRoles("my-role")
@Interceptors({InterceptorClass1.class, InterceptorClass2.class, InterceptorClass3.class})
public class xxxxxV1 extends HttpServlet implements xxxxx {...}
```

I'm using a web.xml to define the servlet alias and a weblogic.xml file to define the context root I want to use.

The problem is, if I leave the @Stateless annotation, when deploying I get the following exception:

```
Target state: deploy failed on Server services_server
javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: my-webservice-name-impl-1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war#MyWebServiceName is already bound; remaining name 'app/wsee'
    at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Jsr88Operation.report(Jsr88Operation.java:547)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Deployer.perform(Deployer.java:140)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Deployer.runBody(Deployer.java:88)
    at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:158)
    at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:115)
    at weblogic.Deployer.run(Deployer.java:74)
    ... 15 more
```

On the other hand, if I delete web.xml, I can deploy without error, but of course the URL to my webservice is not the one I want to define: it uses the /`portName`/`serviceName` URL.

And, if I delete the @Stateless annotation, I get the needed URL, but **the interceptors are ignored**, which is logically unacceptable.

I have tried using the `@Transactional` annotation (see commented code above), but interceptors keep getting ignored.

Anyone has an idea of what I'm missing? Ideally, I would use web.xml and @Transactional and get into the interceptors.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround for making everything work as needed: [the delegation pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern).

The webservice class has now the following annotations:

```
@SchemaValidation
@BindingType(javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
@WebService(serviceName = "xxxxx",
        targetNamespace = "http://bla/BusinessServices/yyy/xxxxx/V1",
        wsdlLocation = "META-INF/wsdl/zzz/yyy/xxxxx/V1/xxxxxConcrete.wsdl",
        portName = "xxxxxPort",
        endpointInterface = "ble.businessservices.yyy.xxxxx.v1.xxxxx")
@Transactional(value= Transactional.TransactionFlowType.SUPPORTS, version= Transactional.Version.WSAT12)
@SecurityPolicies(@SecurityPolicy(uri = "my_policy"))
public class xxxxxV1 extends HttpServlet implements xxxxx {...}
```

I then use a delegate class `xxxxxV1Delegate` with the following annotations:

```
@Stateless
@DeclareRoles("my-role")
@Interceptors({InterceptorClass1.class, InterceptorClass2.class, InterceptorClass3.class})
public class xxxxxV1Delegate {...}
```

In this class all the implementation is done (basically copy-pasting what was in the webservice class and deleting the `@Override`s)

The webservice class will inject a `xxxxxV1Delegate` and contain all the `@Override` methods. Each method will just call the exact same method in the delegate class.